# How do I get unionfs installed?

Tags: 10.10

I'm trying to use unionfs in Ubuntu 10.10, but it seems it is no longer in the apt repositories, and it doesn't show up in `/proc/filesystems`, and there is no module for it anywhere under `/usr`. This used to exist before jaunty in the "unionfs-tools" package.

How do I get unionfs installed in Ubuntu 10.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `unionfs-fuse` package (available in Ubuntu releases since Jaunty).

```
sudo apt-get install unionfs-fuse
```

Also have a look at [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aufs/+bug/555410).

(Note: I am by no means knowledgeable about this subject, but hopefully I have provided some helpful links.)

Comment: Btw,: Nowadays, aufs, like unionfs, has also been superseeded by OverlayFS in the kernel.